# Excel Look up multiple values in a list

Tags: excel, list, formula

I have a list of data which I need to put into different accounts based on descriptions but I can't figure out how to automatically put the right code in.

In the picture, `column A` has transaction types such as **OSPX224**, **OSPX229**, etc. Then there is a list of each transaction within these transaction types and a charge total for each type. I would like to have a number automatically entered into each of the yellow cells based on the **OSPX** number for the section. For example, `D1402` should be the account that **OSPX223** goes into, `D1419` should be the account that **OSPX224** goes into.

I can create a reference list on a different tab that has the **OSPX** numbers and the account numbers for each one.

Each transaction list is a different length so sometimes the **OSPX** number is the row above the charge total and sometimes it is 3 pages above. The number of transactions also changes on each report.

Is there any way to do this?
[image: Example]

The answer by Don Pete is very helpful and exactly what I was asking for but now I've run into a new problem. At random points throughout the data there are heading sections. As shown in example 2, the row after the "charge total" is 1 not the next ospx number which means the green column doesn't work. Any ideas on how to find the next ospx number after the charge total row instead of just the next row?

Also, is there any way to have a "0" or nothing in column D instead of the "#N/A"

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2SuA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern remains the same and your new range starts immediately after a **Total** row, it is possible to accomplish this with two additional rows and `Index ()`. Column E will flag **Total** in `Column A` and count each appearance from the beginning of the column. `Column F` will return the respective **OPSX** number which is the value in the cell below the previous Total row, no matter how many rows are in between. the previous . Finally, you can use `Index(Match( ))`to return the respective account. See picture. Coloured cells contain formulas, that can be copied within the row. You'll need to add one Total row on top (here 1400) and enter a start value (e.g. 1; grey cell) in `Row E`.

[image]

Formulas:

```
D1418 =INDEX($J$6:$J$10,MATCH(F20,$I$6:$I$10,0))
E1416 =IF(ISERROR(FIND("Total",A1416)),"",COUNT($E$1400:E1415)+1)
F1414 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1400:A1414,MATCH(E1414-1,$E$1400:E1414,0)+1),"")
```

Edit:
**Regarding the heading:** Are there always 2 rows between **Charge Total** and the required OSPX-number? And does the OSPX-number always have 7 characters? Then you can use this formula to get the OSPX: `=if(A1457="Charge Total"; left(A1444;7);"")`. `Left()` will extract n charactes from a text string, starting left.

**Regarding #N/A:** You can use iferrror() to mask errors as I did in the green formula. Beware that masking errors may lead to corrupt results in case of unexpected events.

Comment: Unfortunately the number of transactions in each type changed from month to month

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for but now I've run into a new problem. Additional information added to the original post.

Comment: There is anything between 0 and 10 rows between the "charge total" row and the "OSPX" row, it changes for each section and isn't the same each month, there's no pattern. The #N/A error fix worked great. Thanks

Comment: Also, yes the OSPX is always those 4 letters and 3 numbers.